# Different clicks and its usage

Tags: javascript, cypress

What is the difference between invoke('click'), click and trigger('click')
Why does sometimes one work and others does not.
How to know in which conditions to use which one?
This is concerning the cypress test i write and i am looking for a way to understand the usage of these 3.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use `click()` because this is the action command in Cypress. I don't think that `invoke('click')` is actually working at all.

`invoke('trigger')` on the other hand is when you want to use it in combination with `invoke('show')`to click an element that is only visible on hover.

`trigger('click')` is only firing the corresponding event but does nothing else. This is explained [in the Cypress documentation for `trigger`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger#Differences).